# Как сделать топ balance для дискорд бота? через JSON

Tags: json, discord.py, discord-api

```
@client.command(aliases = ["$"])
async def balance(ctx,member:discord.Member = None):
    if member == ctx.author or member == None:
        with open('economy.json','r') as f:
            money = json.load(f)
        emb = discord.Embed(description=f'Баланс пользователя **{ctx.author.mention}** - {money[str(ctx.author.id)]["Money"]} ',colour = 0x2f3236)
        await ctx.send(embed= emb)
    else:
        with open('economy.json','r') as f:
            money = json.load(f)
        emb = discord.Embed(description=f'Баланс пользователя **{member.mention}** - {money[str(member.id)]["Money"]} ',colour = 0x2f3236)
        await ctx.send(embed= emb)
```

Comment: не проще ли хранить значения в бд?

Comment: Ваш вопрос немного не ясен для меня, добавьте пояснение что вы подразумеваете под словом "топ", сортировку и вывод пользователей с самым большим балансом, или нечто иное?

Comment: @Innokentie, Вы всё правильно поняли. Я согласен с Merka, для таких целей как `вывод ТОП пользователей`, будет гораздо легче и практичнее хранить данные в БД. Для новичков подойдёт какой-нибудь простенький `sqlite3`, для более опытных - `PostgreSQL`, например.